# What's wrong with my calculations?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

I am trying to solve for theta. I get the wrong result returned, when plugging in values. I am trying to solve for theta and cannot seem to find what's wrong with my calculations.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

Calling $z = \sqrt{v^2u^2+2gh}$ we have

$$
\frac{v^2}{g}(1-2u^2)+\frac{v^3}{g}u(1-u^2)\frac 1z-\frac vg uz=\frac{v}{g z}\left(u v+z\right)((1-u^2)v-u z)=0
$$